# PrimeFaces FileUpload measure the time of upload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to measure the time it takes for the file to be uploaded. I need to measure the time it takes, and in case it's > 2 minutes I want to inform the user that the upload (not the processing of the file) will take longer than expected

```
<p:fileUpload listener="#{fileUploadBean.handleFileUpload}"
              value="#{fileUploadBean.uploadedFile}"
              invalidFileMessage="File invalid.Please choose a XLSX/CSV/ZIP file"
              invalidSizeMessage="The size of your file should not exceed 200MB"
              sizeLimit="2000000000" showButtons="true" 
              accept=".csv,.xlsx,.CSV,.XLSX,.zip,.ZIP"
              allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv|xlsx|CSV|XLSX|zip|ZIP)$/"
              fileLimit="1" dragDropSupport="true" uploadLabel="Upload"
              update="@form :uploadData" 
              id="fileUpload" />
```

Just to mention the file upload works perfectly fine. There is no error and my only problem is how to do the timer.

Comment: There is an "onstart" JavaScript function you could check: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/fileupload

Comment: You might also like https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/timer.jsf

Answer (score 0):

If you want a basic solution, you can use the setTimeout function in JS (You can think of the method as a way to set a timer to run JavaScript code at a certain time.) which fires a remoteCommand in X milliseconds as follows (I have tested with 100 milliseconds to verify that it works):

```
  <h:form id="formFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true"/>
    <p:remoteCommand id="showTimerMessage" name="showTimerMessage" update="growl" actionListener="#{growlView.showTimer}"/>
    <p:fileUpload mode="simple"
                  value="#{helloWorld.file}"
                  update="growl"
                  fileLimit="1"
                  id="fileUpload" />

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false"   onclick="my_timer();"
                     oncomplete="skipMessage();"
                     action="#{helloWorld.upload}" styleClass="p-mt-3 ui-button-outlined p-d-block"/>

</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    let showMessage = true;

    function my_timer() {
        setTimeout( () => {
            if(showMessage) showTimerMessage();
        }, 100);
    }
    function skipMessage() {
        showMessage = false;
    }
</script>
```

and the GrowlView backend:

```
@Named @RequestScoped
public class GrowlView implements Serializable {

public void addMessage(FacesMessage.Severity severity, String summary, String detail) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
            addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(severity, summary, detail));
}

public void showTimer() {
    addMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Timer message", "The upload (not the processing of the file) will take longer than expected");
}}
```

If the file is uploaded in < 100 milliseconds, the showTimerMessage remoteCommand is not fired and the growld will not display your message. In this way, you avoid using external dependecies or libraries.